# Dynamic blocks in django templates

Tags: django-templates

It is a question about django that has found absolutely no answer for me.
Let's suppose I have a site where I display two blocks in the sidebar :

1. A list of the last users who've logged in
2. A list of the last published blog articles

Let's say that these blocks are to be displayed on 80% of the website urls and presented using template files.
The data for these blocks is generated by code (obviously), bt not by url views.

Well, how to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [custom template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

**Edit**: more specifically, look at [inclusion template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Comment: Hi André, I think I would not use them for this purpose. I have found the source code of a small site given for example, and it uses context preprocessors so that it can layout the contents of the context data the way I want.

Comment: But! Template context processors are too much overhead I think and there is maybe something lighter.

Comment: It seems to me, however, that it's the ideal solution. You just stick the tag in your template, and that tag can fetch your navigation bar. This is one of the uses described in the help at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/.

Comment: Hey André, you dit it ! The inclusion tags are exactly what I was looking for actually, generating context data and include it in a template, which is in turn included in another template. So yes, it is the ideal solution, I did not see this while reading the docs.

Comment: Cool! I see you're new to StackOverflow. Don't forget to accept answers when they solve your problem!

Comment: Yep, I'm new. And I've ticked your answer :)