# Dynamic Tags with Django Templates

Tags: django-templates

I'm new to Django Templates and need some advice.

I'm trying to change the H1 depending on the url path.  My proposed solution is to lookup the path and cycle through the array to check for match.

here is a sample array I will maintain in a config file.

```
page_heading = {
  'contact': 'Contact Me',
  'test': 'It\'s only a test',

}
```

So, in this example, if the path is /contact the h1 header would read Contact Me.

So, is this the right strategy? I can't find any code samples on how to do this with Django Templates. Maybe I'm searching the wrong terms.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965819/dynamic-blocks-in-django-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's just the value of the heading ('Contact us', 'About us')
then you can use this line in your template >>
`<h1><a href="{{ heading_path }}">{{ heading_value }}</a></h1>`
and in your views that renders that template all you need to do is add a variable `heading_path` and `heading_value` to the dictionary passed along with the `RequestContext`

Answer (score 0):

What you can perhaps do is maintain a separate template for heading stuff and include that by passing a parameter through the views.

For example let's say you have 2 types of headings so put them in two files and through the views you can say `{'heading': 'template-name'}`

And in the main Django Template

`include {{heading}}`

Thats its.

The other way perhaps can be to define the class-name within the views and inject it into the template using a similar way as described above.